# Weird set of network-related problems (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, networking

My 3-year-old install of Windows 7 has developed a set of problems that may or may not be related.  I have spent way too much time googling for a solution so I thought I would ask the experts (this is my first attempt on superuser).

System config:
3 PCs running Windows 7: Emerald - statically assigned IP, DNS set to Google
Topaz and Onyx, DHCP assigned IP addresses
1 Windows 10 PC: Obsidian also DHCP assigned IP
All running on gigabit ethernet network.  All joined to HOME workgroup.
SB6141 cable modem connected to Time Warner (Spectrum) cable
Netgear R6220 router, various 8 port Trendnet Green switches.
LAN: 192.168.1.xxx

Problem #1:
About 2 months ago, I would be browsing, using Chrome, and get "resolving host.." which finally times out with DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NO_INTERNET.  This typically happens 2 or 3 times a day and lasts only a few minutes and only machine named Emerald.  All other computers on the network are able to access the internet fine.

Solutions tried:
a) reboot cable modem, router and switches.
b) replace ethernet cable and switch ports on switch
c) run sfc /scannow  -- results no integrity violations

Problem #2:
At some point in the last 2 months, I noticed that my security camera software (Blue Iris) running on a IOS app could no longer connect with the Blue Iris software running on Emerald.

Solutions attempted:
a) Thinking the problem was in the Blue Iris config, I edited that and noticed that the IP interface had changed from 192.168.1.2 (Emerald) to 192.168.56.12!  I did a little checking and that subnet is assigned to VirtualBox, which I run occasionally but not in the recent past.  I reset this to Emerald's IP but could still not access via IOS app.  Blue Iris is still working (storing video, etc) and connected to 3 IP cameras.
b) revisited the config for Dyndns on the router
Did not fix it.

Problem #3:
About the same time, I noticed that my old Logitech Squeezebox, which I use to listen to music, could not find the Logitech Media Server (LMS), which runs on, you guessed it: Emerald.  Now LMS has a web-based interface.  I used the LMS control panel and clicked the Web Remote Control button.  The address for the page is http://127.0.0.1:9000/ and Chrome attempts to open the page but only displays: "Loading Logitech Media Server .." with a spinning circle cursor.

Solutions attempted:
Uninstalled and re-installed LMS.  No change.

Problem #4:
Emerald, Topaz, Onyx and Obsidian are all on HOME workgroup.  I notice last week that though I could see and access all the other PCs from Emerald, none of them could see Emerald.
Solutions attempted:
a) using the HomeGroup control pannel, I selected "leave the homegroup" and then rejoined the homegroup.  This did not fix the problem.
b) ran Homegroup troubleshooter, it could not find a problem.

Problem #5:
I run iTunes on Emerald and share the library on that PC with others in the house.  I have noticed that the other computers see "Hunters library" on Emerald but when I attempt to set iTunes to that shared library, it simply times out.
Solutions attempted:
NONE.

At this point, I decided that possibly some software installation that I had done since the first of the year was the cause. I have been running Photoshop CS2 on Emerald for years (I know..) and suddenly I started having issues where windows and palletes would be hidden.  A search turned up lots of hits, this was a recent problem.  Several people said that recent Windows updates had caused the issue and that uninstalling the updates would fix it.  I did uninstall a number of updates and the the problem was fixed temporarily but returned.  I decided to re-install the updates and did so.  I then tried un-installing a bunch of other programs.  None of this helped, but after one un-install, I needed to install something from a CD.  I then found

Problem #6: my Bluray reader/writer was no longer recognized by Windows.  After some prevaricating, I decided to do a system restore.  This did not fix the Bluray reader problem or the any of the other problems.
Solutions attempted:
a) I tried all of the solutions here:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/314060/your-cd-or-dvd-drive-is-not-recognized-by-windows-or-other-programs
None fixed the problem.

At this point I am ready to use my backups to restore my disk to a known good point and try to restore the new files that have accumlated since that point.  That is, unless someone here has a suggestion?
Thanks.

Comment: Please try asking one question at a time. This is far too broad.

Comment: TLDR... Way too much and not easy to follow along clearly....